# What should be in our on-topic section on the FAQ?

Tags: discussion

As you can see, [currently the "What topics can I ask about here?" of our FAQ is blank.](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

[image]

We've been in private beta for over a week now and we're starting to get an idea of what works on our site and what doesn't so let's start trying to construct it.

---

To keep this clean, only post one line of the FAQ per post and put:

## Ask about…

To denote what is on-topic and

## Don’t ask about…

To denote what is off-topic.

Comment: Here is a thought exercise— Do these these prohibitions address problems actually happening? Or are we inventing rules because because that's what we do? We're trying to break some bad habits, and I don't want to see this site jumping right into rule-making where perhaps a problem does not exist at all. Some of these problems might develop someday, but if/when that happens, discuss them in meta, and maybe someday... Rules should be borne of actual problems, but piling on the rules just to have them preemptively isn't going to make this place all that welcoming. Just a thought.

Comment: @RobertCartaino What I've suggested is based off currently asked questions on the main site and questions brought up on the meta. I don't plan on this covering problems we have yet to experience or address problems we are still debating. The intention here is just to give our FAQ _something_ as there are questions being put as [off-topic that point to the blank FAQ](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/288/bands-that-have-split-up-then-using-same-band-name) which at least to me says we don't have an idea what's on and off topic when some things we've actually defined.

Comment: Discussing hypothetical situations are a good exercise to explore your scope. But they shouldn't all be codified in the frequented *help center* until there is an actual, demonstrable problem. Consider if I invite you over for dinner tonight; just know that you are ***not*** allowed to spit in my living room, nor should you hit my kids, and please do not feed brownies to the cat. I'm just saying <grin>.

Comment: Maybe it could be worded as `Is on topic:` or `Is not on topic:` as we're talking about the on-topic section of the faq? I'd otherwise agree that `Ask about...` or `Don't ask about...` is maybe too much of a directive for now. @RobertCartaino I'd invite you to supper but let's leave politics out? :)

Answer (score 7):

## Don’t ask about…

Recommendations of what to listen to.

Answer (score 6):

## Ask about…

The history of songs, musicians/bands/artists /composers/songwriters/ect, and music technology.

Answer (score 6):

## Don’t ask about…

Playing, creating, or preforming music. This is on-topic on [Music: Practice and Theory](https://music.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 6):

#### Don't ask about...

Shopping questions

like 'Where can I buy X?'

Answer (score 2):

### Don't ask about

Identification questions. Including bands, artists, songs, etc.